# Nonetype object has no attributte get_datos()

Tags: python, class, object, instance, nonetype

```
from node import *
from copy import deepcopy
import pygame
from PIL import Image

def buscar_solucion(inicio, solucion):

    visitados=[]
    nodo_i=Nodo(inicio)

    while nodo_i.get_datos() != solucion:

        nodo_i = deep_search(nodo_i,solucion,visitados)

    moves=[]
    moves.append(solucion)

    while nodo_i.get_padre() != None:
        pater=nodo_i.get_padre()
        moves.append(pater.get_datos())
        nodo_i=pater
    moves.reverse()
    print moves

 def operaciones_h(dades):
   r=[]
   i=0
   while dades[i] != dades[-1]:
      s=deepcopy(dades)
      s[i]=dades[i+1]
      s[i+1]=dades[i]
      r.append(Nodo(s))
      i+=1
   return r

def deep_search(ini,sol,visit):

    visit.append(ini.get_datos())

    if ini.get_datos() == sol:
        return ini

    else:
        hijos=operaciones_h(ini.get_datos())
        for hijo in hijos:
            if hijo.get_datos() not in visit:
                hijo.set_padre(ini)
                return deep_search(hijo,sol,visit)
```

The problem I am getting is in line 14, when creating an instance of the Class `Nodo`. The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_datos'
```

The Class is defined in a file called `node.py`. Might the problem be in the import? Or when defining the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `deep_search` function - it doesn't always return anything. Consider for example what happens if `operaciones_h(ini.get_datos())` returns an empty list: the `for hijo in hijos` loop will never be entered. And even then, if all the datos are in `visit`, the `if` statement will never be True and you will never hit the return statement. In both of those cases, the value of `deep_search` will be `None`.

You should ensure that all paths through `deep_search` end with returning a `Nodo` object.

Answer (score 0):

The `nodo_i = deep_search(nodo_i,solucion,visitados)` call returns `None` for some cases. Inside `deep_search` you have the following code:

```
else:
    hijos=operaciones_h(ini.get_datos())
    for hijo in hijos:
        if hijo.get_datos() not in visit:
```

If `operaciones_h` returns an empty list or if none of the `hijo` values matches your `if` statement the function returns `None` and you'll see your exception.